# PHP Session resumes after browser close with new PHPSESSID in Firefox

Tags: php, session, firefox

In Firefox (and Microsoft Edge) I'm seeing something that I assume is impossible.

1. I log into my website and get a `PHPSESSID` of `6a47272fa6d7b4de2292966bf77ddb51`
2. I close Firefox
3. I reopen Firefox and I can see in the options that my website has **no cookies** set (as I expect)
4. I visit website again without Logging in and my session is still active (I'm still logged in) but my `PHPSESSID` is now `7d4117307c86faa7ea9dc7afe6b4b720`

I'm not looking for a fix. I just want to know how this behavior is possible. How could PHP know which Session to resume if Firefox is not sending a `PHPSESSID` after the browser closes?

I don't see this happen in Chrome (the user needs to log in again as you would expect), but I do see it happen in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Did you check what is being passed to a server during a very first request after you reopen a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After paying very close attention to my network tab in Firefox. I discovered that neither PHP nor Firefox remembered that I was logged in.

Rather my website was redirecting me to *Google Sign In* and *Google Sign In* has non session cookies that remembered I was logged in. So it quickly redirected me back to my website creating a new logged in session for the same user.

It was happening so fast it I could not tell that I was being redirected to Google until I watched the network tab.

Thanks Axalix for the suggestion.